# How to modify Print statement so it sits inside a loop for values of angular shear from 0° to 80° in steps of 10°

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
## Class Code ##
# Shear Class Here WITHOUT the plot method
class Shear(object):          

# This is the default constructor to initialise instance variables 
    # This creates a 'null' Box when a Box object is created    
    def __init__(self):     
        # Set attributes of height, width and depth in metres to None
        self.angularShear = 10

# Override __repr__ in the object base class
    # This will print out the current Box object        
    def __repr__(self):     
        return 'Angular Shear: '+str(self.angularShear)+'  Shear Strain: '+str(self.shearStrain())+ 'majorAxis: '+str(self.majorAxis())+ 'minorAxis: '+str(self.minorAxis())
    
# Instance Methods
    # Method to calculate the shearstrain of object    
    def shearStrain(self):       
        return np.tan(self.angularShear*np.pi/180.)

    # Method to calculate the majoraxis shearstrain 
    def majorAxis(self):   
        sigma = self.shearStrain()/2.
        return ((sigma**2+1.0)**0.5)+sigma
    
     # Method to calculate the minoraxis shearstrain
    def minorAxis(self):   
        sigma = self.shearStrain()/2.
        return ((sigma**2+1.0)**0.5)-sigma
```

Comment: There is no print statement here. And consider using properties instead of getters for the derived values

Answer (score 0):

not sure what print statement you are referring to in the title, but a way to print what you are asking for is:

```
import numpy as np
## Class Code ##
# Shear Class Here WITHOUT the plot method
class Shear(object):          

# This is the default constructor to initialise instance variables 
    # This creates a 'null' Box when a Box object is created    
    # MADE ANGULAR SHEER A PARAMETER
    def __init__(self, angularShear):     
        # Set attributes of height, width and depth in metres to None
        self.angularShear = angularShear

# Override __repr__ in the object base class
    # This will print out the current Box object        
    def __repr__(self):     
        return 'Angular Shear: '+str(self.angularShear)+'  Shear Strain: '+str(self.shearStrain())+ 'majorAxis: '+str(self.majorAxis())+ 'minorAxis: '+str(self.minorAxis())
    
# Instance Methods
    # Method to calculate the shearstrain of object    
    def shearStrain(self):       
        return np.tan(self.angularShear*np.pi/180.)

    # Method to calculate the majoraxis shearstrain 
    def majorAxis(self):   
        sigma = self.shearStrain()/2.
        return ((sigma**2+1.0)**0.5)+sigma
    
     # Method to calculate the minoraxis shearstrain
    def minorAxis(self):   
        sigma = self.shearStrain()/2.
        return ((sigma**2+1.0)**0.5)-sigma


#STUFF ADDED HERE
def main():
     for i in range(0, 81, 10):
          print(repr(Shear(i)))
main()
```

[EDIT reponse to comment]

```
    import numpy as np


## Class Code ##
# Shear Class Here WITHOUT the plot method
class Shear(object):

    # This is the default constructor to initialise instance variables
    # This creates a 'null' Box when a Box object is created
    # MADE ANGULAR SHEER A PARAMETER
    # def __init__(self):
    #     # Set attributes of height, width and depth in metres to None

    # Override __repr__ in the object base class
    # This will print out the current Box object
    def __repr__(self):
        return_string = ""
        for i in range(0, 81, 10):
            return_string +='Angular Shear: ' + str(i) + ';  Shear Strain: ' + str(
                self.shearStrain(i)) + '; majorAxis: ' + str(self.majorAxis(i)) + '; minorAxis: ' + str(self.minorAxis(i)) + "\n"
        return return_string

    # Instance Methods
    # Method to calculate the shearstrain of object
    def shearStrain(self,angularShear):
        return np.tan(angularShear * np.pi / 180.)

    # Method to calculate the majoraxis shearstrain
    def majorAxis(self,angularShear):
        sigma = self.shearStrain(angularShear) / 2.
        return ((sigma ** 2 + 1.0) ** 0.5) + sigma

    # Method to calculate the minoraxis shearstrain
    def minorAxis(self, angularShear):
        sigma = self.shearStrain(angularShear) / 2.
        return ((sigma ** 2 + 1.0) ** 0.5) - sigma


#STUFF ADDED HERE
def main():
    print(repr(Shear()))


main()
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough with my question as I was limited to a specific word count. I was referring to the 12th line '# This will print out the current Box object' so that the statement sits inside a loop that prints the properties of the shear class object for values of angular shear from 0° to 80° in steps of 10°.

Comment: I refactored the code with your comment in mind. Does the assignmnet require you make this Shear class?